# Is this account of root privileges in UNIX correct?

Tags: security, users, root, passwd

Some university lecture notes claim that

> In Unix systems, it is written into the operating system that some functionalities can only be accessed by the `root` user: modifying passwords, accessing to network ports used for communication protocols, interaction with hardware, etc.

Is this description correct? Where exactly is this implemented "in the OS"? How can non-root users change their own passwords if they cannot write `/etc/passwd`?

As far as I know, there are UNIX-based systems like SELinux, where the root user doesn't have unlimited powers?

Comment: Is the latest incarnation of Apple's Mac operating system still a real (read: certified OR wholly-compliant to spec [unlike Linux]) UNIX? If so, that is an example of a real UNIX where root has limited power. `passwd` is SUID. I feel that most of these restrictions are placed by the utilities and filesystem permissions rather than "the OS", but there are some assumptions "the OS" makes (e.g. the init system is run as UID 0)

Comment: Well, I guess OSX is just nix, isn't it?

Comment: I've been prompted to check. macOS 10.12 and 10.13 on Intel-based computers are still certified by The Open Group. And some parts of the filesystem are non-writable by root under any circumstances on these systems (though you can boot to single-user mode and disable this). That was mostly just a response to your last paragraph

Comment: Putting a question mark at the end does not of itself turn a declarative statement into a question.  If you want your last paragraph to be a question, then frame it as an actual question, not as something that has been incorrectly punctuated.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this description correct?

Yes and no, these statements are incomplete at best.  More precisely:

- Modifying passwords: users can change their own password, but only `root` can change the passwords of other users.  This is enforced by access permissions on `/etc/shadow`.  The `passwd(1)` binary can bypass permissions on `/etc/shadow` because `passwd` is setuid to `root`, and thus it can gain `root`'s privileges to write to `/etc/shadow`.
- Accessing to network ports used for communication protocols: only `root` can bind TCP and UDP ports below 1024, but everybody can bind any other port.  This is enforced by the kernel.  Also only `root` can use raw sockets (in particular this is why `ping` needs to be setuid to `root` to run).  But the details of accessing raw sockets are OS-dependent, and access can sometimes be granted by various non-standard ACL mechanisms.
- Interaction with hardware: in principle only `root` processes can send raw commands to hardware.  This is mainly enforced by permissions to the devices in `/dev`.  However most systems have mechanisms to allow users to bypass these permissions, f.i. to mount USB disks, write CDs, use audio hardware, etc.

> Where exactly is this implemented "in the OS"?

There is a system of permissions implemented by the kernel.  Most OSes supplement this system with various other mechanisms, such as OpenBSD's [`pledge`](http://man.openbsd.org/pledge), or Linux's `SELinux`.

> As far as I know, there are UNIX-based systems like SELinux, where the root user doesn't have unlimited powers?

Yes.

Comment: Here's some more good info on this:

http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/5/passwd

https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/src/passwd.c

Comment: @jdwolf `passwd(5)` is the file `/etc/passwd`.  I'm referring to the binary, `passwd(1)`.  As for the Debian binary, I'm not sure what's your point.  It is meant to run [setuid root](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/src/passwd.c#n1139), which allows users to change their own password.

Answer (score 2):

Lets go back to the original statement because I think its incorrect to compare to Linux here since Linux is not Unix.

The manual for the passwd command on Unix specifically states only root can use the utility.

http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/5/passwd

Similarly opening ports only privileged processes are allowed to change to certain ports. The sys/socket.h is defined under Unix.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html

and as described here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

Permissions for this amounted to requiring root.

Interaction with hardware is slightly more broad even vague. But is likely referring to the fact that /dev/ interfaces such as mknod required root.

So the statement is essentially accurate.

Comment: It's also interesting to compare to Linux which for example uses a privilege system. Udev allows various levels of access to hardware. Passwd allows the same user to change their own passwd. And Linux uses PAM instead of just the getuid syscall. So none of these statements are true if we try to apply it to Linux.

Comment: _The manual for the passwd command on Unix specifically states only root can use the utility._ - You're reading `passwd(5)`, the manual for the file `/etc/passwd`.  Apparently UNIX didn't have a `passwd(1)` back then, but [it did](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/passwd) in V6, and the man page explicitly states the user can change his own password.

Comment: Thats a good point. You should edit it into the answer.